# How do I access a object's method when the method's name is in a variable?

Tags: python

Say I have a class object named test.

test has various methods, one of them is whatever() .

I have a variable named method = "whatever"

How can I access the method using the variable with test?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think you need this?  Can you provide the rest of the code.  Usually there's a simpler way to do this that doesn't involve determining a method name via a string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get the attribute with `getattr`:

```
method = "whatever"
getattr(test, method)
```

You can also call it:

```
getattr(test, method)()
```

Answer (score 2):

To *access* the method, `getattr(test, test.method)`; this way you can bind it to a variable, return it as a function result, pass it as an argument, and so forth.  To *call* it as well, append parenthesized arguments (just parentheses if there are no arguments), for example `getattr(test, test.method)()`.